# Why cant Jboss AS 7.1 with Hornet Que - Message Driven Bean use pooled connection?

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq, jboss-mdb

We are trying using HornetQ for messaging on Jboss AS 7.1 and the documentation at

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Messaging+configuration
 says

There is also a pooled-connection-factory which is special in that it leverages the outbound adapter of the HornetQ JCA Resource Adapter.  It is also special because:

```
* It is only available to local clients, although it can be configured to point to a remote server.
* As the name suggests, it is pooled and therefore provides superior performance to the clients which are able to use it.  The pool size can be configured via the max-pool-size and min-pool-size attributes.
* It should only be used to send (i.e. produce) messages.
* It can be configured to use specific security credentials via the user and password attributes.  This is useful if the remote server to which it is pointing is secured.
```

Every thing made sense except the third bullet which says

*** It should only be used to send (i.e. produce) messages.**

My mdb uses Pooled connection factory and is consuming messages (Not sending).

My understanding is Pooled connection factory is what the MDB should use for better performance. Also the hornetq Author's say

http://hornetq.blogspot.com/2011/06/hornetq-on-jboss-as7.html

```
 The pooled connection factories also define the incoming connection factory for MDB's, 
the name of the connection factory refers to the resource adapter name used by the MDB,
```

Can some guru's throw some light on this ?

Thanks
Rama

Answer (score 3):

This is something we try to make it easier for users but still some confusion.

the JCA Adapter specifies InBound Connections and Outbound connections...

InBound connections are used by MDBs and outBounds are done through using the JNDI and instantiating connections.

InBound connections don't need pooling for instance as they just instantiate the consumers for the MDBs and stay up as long as you have an MDB...

We keep definitions on the PooledConnection factories for defining the MDBs but underneath there are a few things happening as I said.

So, we could maybe reword this item you mentioned to explain that better.

Comment: Thank Clebert.Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Now it makes sense as why MDB need not use pooled connection factory.